# How can I use real applications with a simulated network and nodes in ns-3?

Tags: networking, ns-3

I want to simulate a large network, but also use real applications to drive the simulation through. For example, an external application will decide the next simulated node's position based on the KPIs of the simulated network.

Is this achievable in [ns-3](https://www.nsnam.org/)? And if so, is there an example that I can follow?

Comment: Do you just want to simulate movement of Nodes? Or is there anything else that needs to interface with "the real world"?